# Not waiting for scanner input, throwing ElementNotFoundException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

So I'm trying to write a simple menu, where a few options are printed to the screen and then I ask the user for which option they want. Whatever they type should get saved and send them to one of the menu options. Instead it gives me a "NoSuchElementException" at line 20 (String userInput = user.next();) . I don't have any .nextInt() please help.

I've tried doing a while(user.hasNext()) {} and if(user.hasNext()){} and trying them both together. I either get the exception or it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

```
public static void menu(Pet myPet) {


    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Welcome, " + myPet.getName());

    while(true) {

        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(". What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("Games Feed Walk Status");
**Error**   String userInput = user.next();

        if (userInput.equals("Games")) {
```

It should just wait for the input. I've tried just setting userInput and it seems to work then, but then in my Games menu I have a similar set up and it breaks in there too.

Comment: Are you closing `System.in` anywhere else? Can you provide a [mcve] for us to try to reproduce this ourselves?

Comment: Also, don't create a Scanner in a loop as it will most likely break all future Scanners reading from stdin (it will buffer user input, making it inaccessible to other scanners). Define the scanner outside of the loop to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have all of your source code but it seems like you are invoking `close()` on the scanner in your while loop.

The following snippet works:

```
        while (true) {

        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(". What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("Games Feed Walk Status");
        String userInput = user.next();

        System.out.println(userInput);
    }
```

Prompting correctly:

```
. What would you like to do?
Games Feed Walk Status
test1
test1
. What would you like to do?
Games Feed Walk Status
test2
test2
```

However, adding a `close()` invocation on the scanner within the loop recreates the exception you describe.

```
        while (true) {

            Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println(". What would you like to do?");
            System.out.println("Games Feed Walk Status");
            String userInput = user.next();

            System.out.println(userInput);
            user.close(); // The offending line!
        }
    }
```

```
Games Feed Walk Status
test1
test1
. What would you like to do?
Games Feed Walk Status
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at Test.main(Test.java:11)
```

Closing the scanner will also flush the underlying stream and release it back to the OS then deem it useless for the remainder of application lifecycle. If you need to reuse the Scanner you should close it when, and only when you are done with it.

Comment: I have no .close() line in my code. I thought that maybe the error was because I wasn't closing it.